# Update value of object in list

Tags: python, list, methods, replace

I have several lists that each contain objects.  All objects have the values "name" and "amount".  What I want to do is create a method to update "amount" by first finding the item in the list by user input (enter name to find name) then adding or subtracting a user input value (enter value to add/enter value to subtract).

How would I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far (It's incomplete but it's all I could get done):

```
Containers = []
Lids = []
Wicks = []
Labels = []
Misc = []

    class item(object):

        #Constructor
        def __init__(self, name, amount):
            self.name = name
            self.amount = amount

        #Accessors
        def getName(self):
            return self.name

        def getAmount(self):
            return self.amount


        #Mutators
        def __str__(self):
            return "[Name: " + self.name + \
                    ", Amount: " + self.amount + \
                    "]"

        def addAmount():
            found = False
            name = input("Enter the name of a container you wish to change: ")
            addNewAmount = input("Enter the amount you wish to add: ")
            for item in Containers:
                if name in item.getName():
                    found = True
                    position = Containers.index(name)
                    print(Containers[position])
            if not found:
                print("No names match that input.")

        def subtractAmount():
            update = input("Enter a new amount to subtract: ")
            self.amount = amount - update

        def addContainer():
            name = input("Enter a name for the new container: ")
            amount = input("Enter an amount for the new container: ")
            return item(name, amount)

        def addLid():
            name = input("Enter a name for the new lid: ")
            amount = input("Enter an amount for the new lid: ")
            return item(name, amount)

        def addWick():
            name = input("Enter a name for the new wick: ")
            amount = input("Enter an amount for the new wick: ")
            return item(name, amount)

        def addLabel():
            name = input("Enter a name for the new label: ")
            amount = input("Enter an amount for the new label: ")
            return item(name, amount)

        def addMisc():
            name = input("Enter a name for the new misc item: ")
            amount = input("Enter an amount for the new misc item: ")
            return item(name, amount)

        def main():
            running = True
            while running:
                print("Enter a number to start.")
                print("1) Add new container         2) Add new lid")
                print("3) Add new wick              4) Add new label")
                print("5) Add new misc Item         6) Print Inventory")
                print("7) Add Amount from item      8) Subtract Amount from item")
                print("10) quit")
                print("11) print list")
                choice = input("> ")
                if choice == "1":
                    Containers.append(addContainer())
                elif choice == "2":
                    Lids.append(addLid())
                elif choice == "3":
                    Wicks.append(addWick())
                elif choice == "4":
                    Labels.append(addLabel())
                elif choice == "5":
                    Misc.append(addMisc())
                elif choice == "6":
                    print("<==========Containers==========>")
                    for i in Containers:
                        print(i)
                    print("<=============Lids=============>")
                    for i in Lids:
                        print(i)
                    print("<=============Wicks============>")
                    for i in Wicks:
                        print(i)
                    print("<============Labels============>")
                    for i in Labels:
                        print(i)
                    print("<==========Misc Items==========>")
                    for i in Misc:
                        print(i)
                elif choice == "7":
                    return addAmount()
                elif choice == "8":
                    return subtractAmount()
                elif choice == "10":
                    quit()
                elif choice == "11":
                    print('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, Containers)))
                else:
                    print("Invalid entry, please try again.")

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. The first is whether you want containers, lids, wicks, etc to all be the same type of object ("item") or whether it would make more sense to have subclasses. Assuming you want them all to be the same ("item") you could adjust your methods according to the code below (I've left out a lot of options for simplicity).

A couple things to note:

1. "amount" needs to be numerical (int) in order to add or subtract from it correctly
2. the creation of an item is a function outside the class, and allocates the item to the appropriate list (Containers, Lids)
3. the "add_amount" function looks through all lists of all items to find a possible match and adjusts the amount accordingly. If a lid and container have the same name, it will modify the first match.

   ```
   Containers = []
   Lids = []
   Items = [Containers, Lids]

   class item(object):

       #Constructor
       def __init__(self, name, amount):
           self.name = name
           self.amount = amount

       #Accessors
       def getName(self):
           return self.name

       def getAmount(self):
           return self.amount

       def __str__(self):
           return "[Name: " + self.name + \
               ", Amount: " + str(self.amount) + \
               "]"

   def addItem():
       global new_item
       name = input("Enter a name for the new item: ")
       amount = int(input("Enter an amount for the new item: "))
       new_item = item(name, amount)
       return new_item


   def add_amount():
       found = False
       name = input("Enter the name of the item you wish to change: ")
       add_amount = int(input("Enter the amount you wish to add: "))
       for itemList in Items:
           for item in itemList:
               if name == item.getName():
                   found = True
                   position = itemList.index(item)
                   item.amount += add_amount
                   print(itemList[position])
               if not found:
                   print("No names in match that input.")

   def main():
       running = True
       while running:
           print("Enter a number to start.")
           print("1) Make a container         2) Make a lid")
           print("3) add amount               4) quit")
           choice = input("> ")
           if choice == "1":
               addItem()
               print new_item.amount
               Containers.append(new_item)            
           elif choice == "2":
               addItem()
               print new_item.amount
               Lids.append(new_item)
           elif choice == "3":
               add_amount()        
           elif choice == "4":
               quit()
           else:
               print("Invalid entry, please try again.")

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this code out and now I'm stuck at an error: "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'amount'.  Not sure why this is happening.  It's happening on line 83 in print(new_item.amount).

amount is definitely added as a variable in the global variable new_item.

And if I remove all the print(new_item.amount) lines from each choice in the bottom code then I get an error at Containers.append(new_item)) telling me "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"

Also the addAmount(): method is incomplete still not changing a value at the position.

Comment: I got it to work.  I was calling something as a method with () at the end that shouldn't have been there and it was giving me the error.  Thanks for all  your help!  I even got the file to export the lists to an external file for storage and then load them upon loading the program!

Answer (score 0):

This might be kind of messy, but should do the work:

```
  def subtractAmount():
      containers = [Containers, Lids, Wicks, Labels, Misc]
      names = ['Containers', 'Lids', 'Wicks', 'Labels', 'Misc']
      print('Select the number of list you want to search for item')
      print('\n'.join('{}) {}'.format(str(idx), lst_name) for (idx, lst_name) in enumerate(names, 1)))
      selected = input(': ')) - 1
      item_name = input('Enter the item name you are looking for: ')
      item = None
      for value in containers[selected]:
         if value.getName().lower() == item_name.lower():
         item = value
         break
      else:
          print('No item was found with that name!')
      new_amount = input('Enter the new amount for item: ')
      item.amount = new_amount
```